# Disable StyleCop for specific lines

Tags: .net, stylecop

We're using StyleCop in our C# projects. In some cases we'd like to avoid the rules though. I know you can add `// <auto-generated />` in the beginning of the file to make StyleCop ignore it. However, I don't want to ignore the rules for the whole file - only a block of code within it.

Can I disable StyleCop for specific lines somehow?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can suppress rules by adding attributes to blocks of code. Here's a simple example on a class from the blog post linked below, but you can do it on various members individually:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1600:ElementsMustBeDocumented")]
public class MyUndocumentedClass
{
    public void MyUndocumentedMethod {}
}
```

There's a [quick overview](http://blogs.msdn.com/sourceanalysis/archive/2009/08/10/rule-suppressions.aspx) at an MSDN blog post and a [fuller description of the attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks! This should work, though I was hoping for a simpler approach. Was hoping for an method where I can simply say "ignore StyleCop for these lines" - instead of having to find the correct text for style names etc. Awaiting to see if this is possible.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible - the ability to suppress messages is itself a fairly recent addition.

Comment: Thanks. You're probably right then, but I'm gonna leave the question out there for a little longer..

Comment: Well - no new answers for a week, so assume my wish isn't achievable yet then.. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Note that you'll need a Justification="" parameter for that attribute - or you'll get the StyleCop warning SA1404: "A Code Analysis suppression must contain a non-empty justification describing the reason for the suppression."

Comment: To have StyleCop ignore "these lines" wrap the lines in a region and have the opening region contain the words "generated code" (like "This is not generated code but rather code that StyleCop should ignore."

Comment: Can I add these somehow to a region?

Answer (score 13):

An old question I know but in looking for an answer I found that in stylecop 4.4 you can now put something like this - or one of these lines on a method:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "*", Justification = "Risky to change manually")]
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.SpacingRules", "*", Justification = "Risky to change manually")]
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.MaintainabilityRules", "*", Justification = "Risky to change manually")]
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.LayoutRules", "*", Justification = "Risky to change manually")]
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.NamingRules", "*", Justification = "Risky to change manually")]
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.ReadabilityRules‌​", "*", Justification = "Risky to change manually")]
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.OrderingRules", "*", Justification = "Risky to change manually")]
```

- Note: I might be missing one or two of the rule categories

Comment: This did the trick for me. FYI, I editted the last two messages since they had "Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp" duplicated in the namespace

Comment: I recently had to add this for a library class and found that I needed [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.ReadabilityRules", "*", Justification = "This is library code")] as well

Comment: Ordering rules is another one you may need to add: `[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.OrderingRules", "*", Justification = "Risky to change manually")] `

Answer (score 6):

This [guy](http://idispensable.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/disabling-stylecop-for-single-file.html) seems to have a good general ignore hack; he suggests putting this at the top of the file - tested and working with R#

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
// This code was generated by a tool.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Handy for when you are just churning out a load of boilerplate to adhere to a mainly unimplemented interface, for example.

Comment: You should not add this header, if your code is not auto generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the piece of code between a region name Generated Code and it will be ommited.

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your class or method with the following StyleCop attribute:

```
[GeneratedCode("Tool Goes Here", "Message Goes Here")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a block of code like so:

```cs
// some other code before and after

#pragma warning disable SA1008 // Opening parenthesis must not be preceded by a space
     (_, value) => (key, value)))
#pragma warning restore SA1008
```